# Run basic rspec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby and RSpec. I want to create very simple RSpec test:

```
# test_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe TestController  do 

    puts(Time.now)

end
```

But when I run the code this way `rspec test_spec.rb` I get error:

```
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant TestController (NameError)
```

Can you give me some idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: `3pController` is not a valid constant name. Constants start with an uppercase letter. They must not start with a digit.

Comment: Well, now I get `No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead` Any recommendation how I can fix this?

Comment: That's just a notice that no DRb server (like [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork)) is running. It doesn't mean that RSpec is not working.

Comment: Done. Probably some import is missing?

Comment: Do you have a `TestController` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, can I run the code without it?

Comment: Instead of a class, you can pass a string to `describe`, e.g. `describe "my first test" do`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Put the code inside the describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a class to `describe`, RSpec attempts to create an instance of that class. If the specified class does not exist, you get an error.

You can pass a string instead:

```
describe "my first test" do
  it "does something" do
    expect(1).to be_odd
  end
end
```

Running the above:

```
$ rspec -fd test_spec.rb

my first test
  does something

Finished in 0.00178 seconds (files took 0.10381 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is because after the describe you need a string with the description and you are leaving it without quotes.

```
describe '3pController'  do 
    puts(Time.now)
end
```

But the tests should be structured as follows

1. a (describe) can have many (it) inside (a (it) is where the tests are)
2. one (decribe) can have more (describe) inside or can have (context), that these at the same time has many (it).

inside this link I will leave the documentation [Basic structure](http://https:%20/%20/relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it.)

Here you can see a basic example of a test

```
describe 'sum 2 + 2 equal 4' do
   it { expect(2 + 2).to eq(4)}
end
```